# Extraction of values from pandas column which is a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

A pandas dataframe called top_chart_movies, which has a column, **genres**, that has a list of dictionaries as shown in the picture below [image]

The column values has varying number of dictionary items within a list.

How to extract the values as a list and include it into another column **genres1**, where

top_chart_movies['genres1'].head(2)

```
1881  ["Drama","Crime"]
3337 ["Drama","Crime"]
```

I tried this following code, but it didn't work.

```
top_chart_movies['genres1'] = [value for key, value in top_chart_movies['genres']]
```

Edit:
When I type the following code

```
top_chart_movies['genres'].iloc[1]
```

I get:

```
'[{"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]'
```

So, the values are stored as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
top_chart_movies['genres1'] = [[genres_item['name'] for genres_item in genres_list] for genres_list in top_chart_movies["genres"]]
```

How this works: If we iterate over `top_chart_movies["genres"]`, like this: `for genres_list in top_chart_movies["genres"]` then for each row, the `genres_list` would contain a list of dictionaries with keys `"id"` and `"name"`. For example, in the first row, `genres_list` would be `[{"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]`.

For each row, we iterate over `genres_list`, for example `for genres_item in genres_list`, each iteration in `genres_item` we get a dictionary. For example,  `{"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}`. Then we take only the `"name"` part: `genres_item["name"]`.

So, for each row, to get list of `"name"` elements of the genres, we do `[genres_item['name'] for genres_item in genres_list]` and we do this in every row like this:  `[[genres_item['name'] for genres_item in genres_list] for genres_list in top_chart_movies["genres"]]`

**Edit:**

As the question poster pointed out, it turns out that the genres list is in string representation. However, it isn't specified whether it is python's string representation or json string representation or other. Hence, we must parse it either with `json.loads` or using `ast.literal_eval`.

If it is in json string, this should work:

```
import json
top_chart_movies['genres1'] = [[genres_item['name'] for genres_item in json.loads(genres_list)] for genres_list in top_chart_movies["genres"]]
```

If it is in python string representation, this should work:

```
from ast import literal_eval
top_chart_movies['genres1'] = [[genres_item['name'] for genres_item in literal_eval(genres_list)] for genres_list in top_chart_movies["genres"]]
```

Comment: Thanks. it didn't work. I get the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. I notice that the values are stored as string with single quotes at the end.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was a python string implementation. The second solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_genre(lst):
    return [item["name"] for item in lst]

top_chart_movies['genres1'] = top_chart_movies['genres'].map(get_genre)
```

You don't need all the values associated to every key, but only the ones corresponding to each key `["name"]`.

Once you know how to extract them from one list, you can [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) that function to your column of lists.

Comment: Thanks. it didn't work. I get the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. I notice that the values are stored as string with single quotes at the end.